# ping google.com or 8.8.8.8 fails

Tags: networking, centos, ping, yum, ifconfig

I am using Cent OS 6.4 and it is in a official lab.

ping google.com gives the below output and hangs:

[root@LAB1 ~]# ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.236.195) 56(84) bytes of data.

ping 8.8.8.8 also yields the same result. I am able to access internet from browser(Mozilla). Is there a problem with the network settings or configuration?

Below is the output from traceroute - n 8.8.8.8 
[root@LAB1 ~]# traceroute -n 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  *^Z

Below is the output from route -n if it helps

[root@LAB1 ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0

As I am new to networking, I am not able to identify the issue. Any help here is much appreciated...

**Edit** : The main reason for me to try the above ping is to resolve an yum update command that fails to resolve the mirror sites...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICMP is'nt allowed outgoing through the firewall / router behind you are accessing Internet.

This

```
[root@LAB1 ~]# ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.236.195) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

And the fact you can browse the web means you are resolving google.com (DNS protocol)

traceroute use ICMP two.

Comment: Archinoa is probably right... you may get closer to confirmation if ping is also unsuccessful for any other external IP address you try.

Comment: `ICMP is'nt allowed outgoing through the firewall / router behind you are accessing Internet` ... really?

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses...@James, other external IP addresses are also not working...Now, the main reason I am trying this ping is because, yum update doesn't work... it gives a PYCURL 6 error and says hosts could not be resolved...could these be related? Is there a way to resolve these issues?

Comment: Is it only showing error about this package ?
Otherwise maybe you need to comment out some repository entry in the file /etc/yum.repos.d.

Yum is reaching repository by http, so icmp isn't matter here.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Archinoa. I have posted a separate question for the yum update failure in superuser. I will accept your answer as I got the point that ping uses ICMP which is blocked through the firewall and since the actual issue is with Yum update, I will not try ping anymore to check for internet access :).