# Unable to ping VM outside windows Azure

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, ping, azure-connect, azure-virtual-network

I followed the following link to create the azure instance
http://michaelwasham.com/2013/09/03/connecting-clouds-site-to-site-aws-azure/

I am able to ssh to the VM from my local machine, however I am not able to ssh or ping from the VM to any public servers (www.google.com, www.yahoo.com).That is the communication is happening only between VMs within the Windows azure Cloud.

Please let me know how to enable outbound traffic to public servers from Windows Azure VM.

Answer (score 2):

ICMP is blocked by default (see this SO post: [ping google.com or 8.8.8.8 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962649/ping-google-com-or-8-8-8-8-fails)) for the Virtual IP Address

But with the new `instance level public-ip address`, you will get an ip address per virtual server:
https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/

Now ping works (ping 8.8.8.8) after a reboot of the VM in my case.